# Flux not emitting values as expected

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

Reactive programming, I have 3 spring boot microservices using webflux module.
Service1  produces Integers with delay of 1 seconds between each emission
Service2  produces Strings(city names) with delay of 5 seconds between each emission
ServiceMain consumes both service1 and 2 through REST API ,  gets Flux < Integer> & Flux< String> and combines them using Flux<Tuple2<Integer,String>> and returns to the google chrome browser.

My expected results in the browser was after 5 second interval it would emit objects like this, combining an int with a each emitted string

```
[{"t1":0,"t2":"London"},[{"t1":1,"t2":"Paris"},{"t1":2,"t2":"Rome"},{"t1":3,"t2":"Amsterdam"}]
```

What I get after 5 seconds is

```
[{"t1":0,"t2":"LondonParisRomeAmsterdam"}]
```

service1 Int producing function looks like this

```
@GetMapping("/stream/")
public Flux<Integer> getIntsStream()
{
    return Flux.range(0, 10000)
    .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .doOnNext(i -> System.out.print("int pushing " + i));
    
}
```

In service2 String producing function is as follows

```
    @GetMapping("/stream/")
public Flux<String> getStringStream()
{               
     List<String> cities = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("London", "Paris", "Rome", "Amsterdam"));
    
      Flux<String> flux = Flux.fromIterable(cities);
      return flux.delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(5))       
      .doOnNext(i -> System.out.print("pushing " + i));
        
}
```

endpoint/method in servicemain is below

```
@GetMapping("/stream-combined/")
public Flux<Tuple2<Integer, String>> getCompositeStream()
{
    
    String url1 = "http://localhost:9001/ints/stream/";         
    String url2 = "http://localhost:9002/strings/stream/";
       
    Flux<Integer> f1 =  webClient.
                get().uri(url1)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Integer.class)
                .log(LOG.getName(), Level.FINE);
        
    Flux<String> f2 =  webClient.
                get()
                .uri(url2)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(String.class)
                .log(LOG.getName(), Level.FINE);        
     
     return Flux.zip(f1, f2);  
}
```

Comment: I think it is due to the fact that by default, Webflux map `Flux<String>` to a `text/plain` HTTP body, without considering separation between input flux elements (or arbitrarily). I think that you have to manually specify a text stream response, as shown in the following answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75587800/how-can-i-write-code-in-java-to-receive-a-text-event-stream-event-stream-and-pri